# Installing Ubuntu with "something else"

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

After having some trouble with Ubuntu installation, I think I've finally figured out what needs to be done. My system's current partition setup is like this: SYSTEM 200MB primary, C: 670GB primary, 28GB unallocated (for Ubuntu), and HP_TOOLS 100MB primary. So here's what I'm going to try to do. In Ubuntu installation with the "something else" option I will create a primary ext4(or 3?) partition out of the 28GB of free space. Then, since I now have four primary partitions, I will create a logical 4GB SWAP area inside the ext4(or 3?) area. So the end result should be that along with the SYSTEM, C:, etc. I will have a 24GB partition for Ubuntu and inside that a 4GB logical SWAP partition.

Will this work?

Comment: I suppose you could create a 4GB swap file after installation, but you can't really create a 4GB logical partition in your ext4 filesystem. Maybe you mean use LVM on the 28GB partition. And then ext4 on the vg?

Comment: First create the SWAP at then end of the HDD then make the ext4 partition on the space left and choose as mount point `/`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Partitions are fairly new to me, so I'm not quite sure what LVM and VG stand for.

Comment: @Cornelius Sounds like a plan, I'll try it here in a bit.

Comment: I think the comments got deleted for some reason. I'm almost ready to get it installed. Before I do I would like to know what the "Format?" option is and if I should use it. Also, does it matter if swap is listed before or after the ext4 partition? @floppy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make that 28GB as extended(logical) partition you can't have 4 primary partitions. You already have System,C,HP tools as primary partitions so if you create 24GB primary you cannot create a swap partition. So make 28GB unallocated to extended partition and split it into 24 and 4 GB partitions and install ubuntu.

You cannot create a partition inside a primary partition, the partition should be converted into extended(logical) then split into partitions and all the split partitions will be logical partitions.

Also you can create swap partition anywhere you like.

I hope this helps