# My installer doesn't detect Windows 7

Tags: system-installation

So, this is not technically my first time installing ubuntu but hopefully will be my first successful time. I always get stuck on the partitioning. Right now i hve some 92 gigs set as unallocated, according to windows partitioning tool. According to ubuntu installers "something else" partitioning tool it says it's unusable.

Every tutorial I find online just says to click install alongside windows and presto, all done. But most completly ignore the something else. And my installer can't detect my OS.

So i just want to know how I can install ubuntu. I'm at the point in the installer looking at this:

```
 /dev/sdb                                         <-   there's no size on this one.
 /dev/sdb1  ntfs
 /dev/sdb2  ntfs                               <-biggest one, probably windows
 unusable                                          <-this is where I want ubuntu to go.
 /dev/sdb3  ntfs
 /dev/sdb4  ntfs
```

What do I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [My disk already has 4 primary partitions, how can I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/149821/my-disk-already-has-4-primary-partitions-how-can-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new partition with the unusable memory and remember the /dev/sdaX of that partition. After that follow the answer in below question for installing Ubuntu with something else option.

[How to use manual partitioning during installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation)

for more [Installing Ubuntu with "something else"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452091/installing-ubuntu-with-something-else)